# mod_cache serving the wrong content

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress, httpd, mod-cache

I'm trying to use mod_disk_cache to speed up a web site that is running on WordPress. Whenever I enable it with

```
CacheEnable disk /
```

and the rest being the stock Ubuntu configuration I start to get the wrong results. When I see the main page it's fine, but when I go to a specific post I get a RSS feed instead. Like if the cache is returning the wrong content.

I've disabled my RewriteRules as it seems mod_cache doesn't work with that.

I'm not even sure where to start to debug such a thing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't found why this was happening but I *solved* it by using [WP Super Cache](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-super-cache/); which greatly increased the performance of my Wordpress.

Answer (score 2):

Making a small change to the Rewrite rules in your .htaccess file should solve this.  There is, apparently, a known bug in apache.  I had the exact same problem, albeit a different flavor of unix (FreeBSD), and the fix given at this link below absolutely solved it:  http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12175

Answer (score 0):

Bug?: [Bug #219914 in apache2 (Ubuntu): `mod_disk_cache enabled globally by default`](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/apache2/+bug/219914)